# Robot framework cant load .dll file created by cygwin into python script

Tags: python, c, dll, cygwin, robotframework

C program is compiled and converted into .dll using cygwin compiler.In python scripting it can be loaded using ctypes and call the functions successfully.But I import that python scripting as libraray into Robot Framework Automation tool,it cant load that .dll file and the test case also failed.

is the cygwin created dll file not be supported by RTF?

Can anyone suggest any other method for that?

Comment: Are you running the Robot Framework in Windows or Cygwin?

Comment: in windows command prompt.is there any way to run RTF in cygwin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given our discussion in the comments. You can't mix and match like this. The format that Cygwin builds a DLL in is different that the format Windows expects a DLL in. You need to build and run all in one environment.